# how to handle sub domains in open api spec?

Tags: swagger, oas3, ibm-api-connect

I am preparing open api spec 3.0 for an external system hosted by Government. I am lacking to handle subdomains.

There are two endpoints available as per [Edgar](https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data) and [API Documentation](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/sec-api-documentation)

- [www.sec.gov](http://www.sec.gov)
- data.sec.gov

I came up with server details for Open api spec yaml as follows

```
servers:
  - url: 'https://data.sec.gov'
  - url: 'https://www.sec.gov'
```

But I am not sure if this is the correct approach. I did a quick lookup on Netcraft and found them to be sharing same server details.

How to handle subdomains(www and data) in oas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do `www.sec.gov` and `data.sec.gov` share the same set of API endpoints? (Example: the `/foo/bar` endpoint can be accessed as both `https://www.sec.gov/foo/bar` and `https://data.sec.gov/foo/bar`.) Or are some API endpoints available only on `www.sec.gov` while others are available only on `data.sec.gov`?

Comment: @Helen they have different end points.

Comment: So it was decided to host separate endpoints since internal implementation was not allowing server switching. But keeping this thread open for a better answer